# Show two compute in same column

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I wrote this code and want it display two compute in a same column and different row:

```
COMPUTE COUNT LABEL 'Total Item :' OF subtotal on memberID 
COMPUTE SUM  LABEL 'Total (Yen): ' OF subtotal ON memberID
```

The result is it only display the second compute and didn't display the first compute

```
Total (Yen)      $1137.50
```

The result should be

```
Total Item :      2
Total (Yen):      $1137.50
```

Comment: Stop trying to force SQL to be a front end. This is a SQL Anti-Pattern.

Comment: @MatBailie the question is about using the SQL\*Plus `compute` command, so seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define both the computes in the same statement.

```
break on memberid skip 1

compute count label 'Total Items:' sum label 'Total (Yen):' of subtotal on memberID 

col memberid format a12
col subtotal format $9990D00
```

Confirm how SQL*Plus understood your command:

```
SQL> comp
COMPUTE count LABEL 'Total Items:' sum LABEL 'Total (Yen):' OF subtotal ON memberID
```

```
with demo (memberid, subtotal) as
    ( select 'ABCD', 1.2 from dual union all
      select 'ABCD', 2.3 from dual union all
      select 'DEFG', 4.5 from dual union all
      select 'DEFG', 6.7 from dual union all
      select 'DEFG', 8.9 from dual union all
      select 'WXYZ', 0.1 from dual union all
      select 'WXYZ', 2.3 from dual )
select memberid, subtotal from demo
order by 1, 2;
```

```
MEMBERID      SUBTOTAL
------------ ---------
ABCD             $1.20
                 $2.30
************ ---------
Total Items:         2
Total (Yen):     $3.50

DEFG             $4.50
                 $6.70
                 $8.90
************ ---------
Total Items:         3
Total (Yen):    $20.10

WXYZ             $0.10
                 $2.30
************ ---------
Total Items:         2
Total (Yen):     $2.40


7 rows selected.
```

To add grand totals:

```
break on memberid skip 1 on report

compute count label 'Total Items:' sum label 'Total (Yen):' of subtotal on memberID report
```

```
MEMBERID      SUBTOTAL
------------ ---------
ABCD             $1.20
                 $2.30
************ ---------
Total Items:         2
Total (Yen):     $3.50

DEFG             $4.50
                 $6.70
                 $8.90
************ ---------
Total Items:         3
Total (Yen):    $20.10

WXYZ             $0.10
                 $2.30
************ ---------
Total Items:         2
Total (Yen):     $2.40

             ---------
Total Items:         7
Total (Yen):    $26.00

7 rows selected.
```